# PyCharm custom syntax highlight for XML files

Tags: xml, syntax-highlighting, pycharm

I have many XML files which include parameters with the following syntax:

```
<CustomElement url="http://www.#[domain]/#[sub]" />
```

`#[whatever]` is replaced by a value before runtime but scanning through a lot of elements make it hard to recognize that an element needs a value.

Is it possible to configure PyCharm to highlights only `#[]` parts so it's easier to find the params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to configure this via the UI. You can write a plugin that will highlight those sequences.